# How to get rid of ">>" on vim shows after modification

Tags: shell, vim, editor, macvim

">>" would show up on the sidebar of the vim editor every time I press <jk> (i map them to esc)
This happens in both zsh shell and MacVim app.

[image]

Even a deleting my .vimrc would not help
can anyone please help me

Comment: Might fit better in https://vi.stackexchange.com/ For your question, see `:h :sign`. We don't know your setup but there's probably some external program trying to tell you something about your code.

Comment: If you don't want signs, don't install plugins that create them.

Comment: I would blindly guess that *You Complete Me* is to blame. In that case `let g:ycm_enable_diagnostic_signs = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following mapping will hide all signs (`:h :sign`) when you press `jk` to leave insert mode:

```
:imap jk <Esc>:sign unplace * group=*<CR>
```

This will solve the problem by hiding the sings (read: hide the problem).

However, **this is a dirty hack at best**. It would be far better to find out which program is annotating the file and turn it off there.

From the information provided in the question, there's no telling where the signs might come from.

Comment: thanks a lot. I was trying to find the keyword "sign" so that i can dive in to find the answer. It makes me a lot easier to find the problem with this clue

Comment: Dirty hack indeed. Finding the root cause would be a lot more useful.